# How to use PDFlatex with Tikz package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I have to make a presentation run by PDFlatex. But I want to draw a picture in it with the Tikz package. How can I manage this?

Comment: Tikz works fine with pdfLaTeX: is there a specific point you need help with?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the great [TikZ example gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). You would find more than hundred examples in different categories with the complete source code. Using examples makes starting easier.

On your computer, you can open the very extensive TikZ manual by typing

```
texdoc tikz
```

or `texdoc pgfmanual` at the command prompt. Or follow the link given by Geoffrey ([direct link](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)). In my blog there are several examples, for instance for diagrams and for colorful tables: [TikZ category](http://texblog.net/latex/graphics/pgf-tikz/).

Further you might find interesting:

- The [TikZ Mini Course](http://automatica.dei.unipd.it/people/varagnolo/tikz.html)
- [Graphics with PGF and TikZ](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mertz/) from the PracTeX journal

Or video tutorials:

- [Generating graphics in the spirit of TeX](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/a-tikz-tutorial-generating-graphics-in-the-spirit-of-tex/) (TUG 2009)
- [Graphics with PGF and TikZ](http://www.river-valley.zeeba.tv/conferences/practex2006/entries/william-com.html) (PracTeX 2006)

More resources are listed on http://www.texample.net/tikz/.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading and stepping through the graduated exercises in the wonderful TikZ and PGF manual that comes with the package, downloadable from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/pgf.html). Then consider whether to use the [beamer](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/) package as the container for your TikZ components. From there, you'll be able to ask more directed questions about what to do.  Best of luck!